# Duplicate a Google Slide connected to a Google Sheet to a new instance

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Slide where all its charts are generated via a linked Google Sheet.

At the moment, when I duplicate "Google Slide A" that is connected to "Google Sheet A", the duplicated "Copy of Google Slide A" remains connected to "Google Sheet A", instead of being connected to "Copy of Google Sheet A" - Which is how I want it to be.

I found this line of code from Google Script that solves the problem but can only duplicate the google sheet charts, not the tables.

I want to add the same function for the tables.

**Could anyone help me add to this code the same possibility for tables ?** **(I have 0 coding knowledge)**

Kindly find the code below:

```
//this updates all charts embedded from sheets on all slides of the specified slides id to a specified spreadsheet id
//Intended for use immediately after duplicating both the slide/presentation and the spreadsheet
//For now you must manually enter / cut and paste the ID of both files directly below in the two Id variables inside the quotes

function myFunction() {
  //sheet and slide id's - the charts in the slide id listed here will be linked to the the sheet id listed here:
  var slideId="435345345345345345345345345345345345"; // enter your slide id here
  var spreadsheetId="23423423423423423423423423423434234234"; // enter your sheet id here
  
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var sheet2=ss2.getSheets()[0];
  var chart2=sheet2.getCharts()[0];
  Logger.log('spreadsheet2 name is ' + ss2.getName());
  
  //get all charts from all sheets of the spreadsheet copy
  var sheets2=ss2.getSheets();
  var allCharts=[];//keep track of all charts on all sheets of the spreadsheet
  var allChartsIds=[];//keep track of the ids for all the charts
  var chartsnum=0;
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets2.length; i++) {
    var curSheet2=sheets2[i];
    var charts2 = curSheet2.getCharts();
        for (var j = 0; j < charts2.length; j++) {
          var curChart2=charts2[j];
          allCharts[chartsnum]=curChart2;
          allChartsIds[chartsnum]=curChart2.getChartId();
          chartsnum++;
          Logger.log('\n chart2 Id is ' + curChart2.getChartId());
        }
  }
  
  //total number of charts in all sheets of the spreadsheet
  var lengthAllCharts=allCharts.length;
  
  var pres2 = SlidesApp.openById(slideId);
  Logger.log('pres2 name is ' + pres2.getName());
  
  var slides2=pres2.getSlides();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < slides2.length; i++) {
    var curSlide2=slides2[i];
    var charts2 = curSlide2.getSheetsCharts();
        for (var j = 0; j < charts2.length; j++) {
          var curChart2=charts2[j];
          var chartHeight=curChart2.getHeight();
          var chartWidth=curChart2.getWidth();
          var chartLeft=curChart2.getLeft();
          var chartTop=curChart2.getTop();
          
              for (var k = 0; k < lengthAllCharts; k++) {
                if (curChart2.getChartId()==allChartsIds[k]){
                  var chart2=allCharts[k]; 
                  break;
                } 
              }
          Logger.log('\n chart2 ObjId is ' + curChart2.getObjectId());
          Logger.log('\n chart2 ChartId is ' + curChart2.getChartId());
          Logger.log('\n chart2 Chart data ' + curChart2.getSpreadsheetId());
          curChart2.remove();
          curSlide2.insertSheetsChart(chart2, chartLeft, chartTop, chartWidth, chartHeight);
        }

  }
  
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Kikuchi

Comment: That would be difficult since there are no available methods that can identify where the tables are placed. Charts have their own class but i dont think table have. You might be able to do it if you specify the range of those tables but that would be tiresome.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `At the moment, when I duplicate "Google Slide A" that is connected to "Google Sheet A", the duplicated "Copy of Google Slide A" remains connected to "Google Sheet A", instead of being connected to "Copy of Google Sheet A"`. In this case, when you copy "Google Slide A" connected to "Google Sheet A", you want to copy both "Google Slide A" and "Google Sheet A". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thank you guys so much for your responses! @ASyntuBU thank you for the clarification, it seems like I have to get used to manually linking the tables.

Comment: @Tanaike Your English is great don't worry :) When you duplicate "Google Sheet A", the duplicated "Copy of Google Sheet A" will not be connected to anything. I want it to connect to "Copy of Google Slide A".. That's the whole problem :/

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike When you duplicate a Google Slide that is connected to a Google Sheet, the duplicated Google Slide remains connected to the initial Google Sheet, not to a duplicated Google Sheet. Even if you duplicate the initial Google Sheet, it is not connected to the duplicated Google Slide and cannot be connected.
I have found the solution for this, which is in the code above. But the problem now is that this code can duplicate the charts from one sheet to the other, but not the tables. But because tables don't have a class as mentioned by ASyntuBU, it seems difficult to perform this code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as Kikuchi- I needed to create new instances of a Google Slides file and its "linked" Google Sheets file. I also needed the linked objects in the new Slides file to be linked to the new Sheets file, not the original Sheets file.

As Kikuchi mentions, the code above (originally found in this locked [Google support thread](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/17125948)) works to replace the linked charts, but it doesn't work to replace the linked tables.

Unfortunately, I'm now convinced that Google doesn't offer any API or App Script to achieve exactly what the question is asking regarding tables. However, I was able to find a passable workaround.

Google Sheets now offers a chart type called a **Scorecard chart** and a chart type called **Table chart**. I was able to replace each *single-cell* (1x1) linked table in my Slides file with a Scorecard chart, and I was able to replace each *multi-cell* (e.g. 2x2, 5x4, etc.) linked table in my Slides file with a Table chart.

Scorecard chart and Table chart are both extremely limited in their styling options compared to "real" Sheets tables. Even so, they were both able to add a passable amount of styling to match the style of my Slides. Scorecard chart has slightly more styling options, so I recommend using it whenever you have a 1x1 linked table.

Below is the App Script code I ended up using. It basically does the same thing as the code above- takes 2 template files, duplicates them, and replaces the old charts with new charts. But the old code took me a while to understand, so I hope the new code is a bit more readable.

Also note that your Slides and Sheets file templates cannot have `.xlsx` or `.pptx` file extensions. If they do, you will get errors when the script below tries to open the duplicates. For more info, see this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71966904/2421313).

```
// These are the object IDs of your Sheets and Slides template files.
// To find yours, open the file and look at the URL. For more info, see
// https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts
const SHEETS_TEMPLATE_ID = '1abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ';
const SLIDES_TEMPLATE_ID = '1ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopq';

const NEW_SHEETS_FILE_NAME = 'new-sheets';
const NEW_SLIDES_FILE_NAME = 'new-slides';

// Creates new Sheets and Slides from the templates identified above. Then
// updates the charts in Slides so that they link to the new charts in Sheets.
function duplicate() {
  Logger.log('Creating a new Sheets file by copying the Sheets template...');
  const sheetsTemplateFile = DriveApp.getFileById(SHEETS_TEMPLATE_ID);
  const newSheetsFile = sheetsTemplateFile.makeCopy(NEW_SHEETS_FILE_NAME);
  Logger.log(`\tCreated ${NEW_SHEETS_FILE_NAME}`);

  Logger.log('Finding all charts in the new Sheets file...');
  const chartsMap = {};
  const newSheets = SpreadsheetApp.open(newSheetsFile);
  newSheets.getSheets().forEach((sheet) => {
    sheet.getCharts().forEach((chart) => {
      const chartId = chart.getChartId();
      chartsMap[chartId] = chart;
    });
  });
  const chartCount = Object.keys(chartsMap).length;
  Logger.log(`\tFound ${chartCount} charts`);

  Logger.log('Creating a new Slides file by copying the Slides template...');
  const slidesTemplateFile = DriveApp.getFileById(SLIDES_TEMPLATE_ID);
  const newSlidesFile = slidesTemplateFile.makeCopy(NEW_SLIDES_FILE_NAME);
  Logger.log(`\tCreated ${NEW_SLIDES_FILE_NAME}`);

  Logger.log(`Replacing each chart in ${NEW_SLIDES_FILE_NAME} with its corresponding chart in ${NEW_SHEETS_FILE_NAME}...`);
  const newSlidesId = newSlidesFile.getId();
  const newSlides = SlidesApp.openById(newSlidesId);
  let replacedChartCount = 0;
  newSlides.getSlides().forEach((slide, slideIndex) => {
    slide.getSheetsCharts().forEach((oldChart) => {
      Logger.log(`\t Replacing chart ${1 + replacedChartCount} on slide ${1 + slideIndex}...`);
      const left = oldChart.getLeft();
      const top = oldChart.getTop();
      const width = oldChart.getWidth();
      const height = oldChart.getHeight();
      const chartId = oldChart.getChartId();
      oldChart.remove();

      const newChart = chartsMap[chartId];
      slide.insertSheetsChart(newChart, left, top, width, height);
      replacedChartCount++;
    });
  });
}
```